# Subtyping rules for extension of System $F_\omega$ with subtyping and kind-level variance tracking

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

I need an extension of System $F_\omega$ with subtyping, and where the variance of type constructors is reflected in their kind. Unfortunately, System $F^\omega_{<:}$, as defined in chapter 31 of Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages*, doesn't address the latter requirement, so I decided to roll my own.

Here is the list of additions to $F_\omega$'s I've made so far:

### Polarities

- **Ground forms:** $+$, $-$.
- **Inversion:** $+^\dagger = -$ and $-^\dagger = +$.

### Variances

- **Ground forms:** sets of polarities.
- **Inclusion:** set inclusion.
- **Inversion:** memberwise.

### Kinds

- **Ground forms:** $\Omega/V$ and $K \rightarrow K'$.
- **Inclusion:**

  - Given $V_1 \subseteq V_2$, we can derive $\Omega/V_1 \subseteq \Omega/V_2$.
  - Given $K_2 \subseteq K_1$ and $K_1' \subseteq K_2'$, we can derive $K_1 \rightarrow K_1' \subseteq K_2 \rightarrow K_2'$.

### Types

- **Kinding:**

  - $\Gamma \vdash \top, \bot : \Omega/V$.
  - $\Gamma \vdash (\rightarrow) : \Omega/V^\dagger \rightarrow \Omega/V \rightarrow \Omega/V$.
  - The remaining rules are as one would expect.
- **Inclusion:**

  - Given $\Gamma \vdash T : \Omega/V$ and $\{+\} \subseteq V$, we can derive $\Gamma \vdash \bot \subseteq T \subseteq \top : \Omega/V$.
  - Given $\Gamma \vdash T : \Omega/V$ and $\{-\} \subseteq V$, we can derive $\Gamma \vdash \top \subseteq T \subseteq \bot : \Omega/V$.
  - Given $\Gamma \vdash T_1, T_2 : \Omega/\{+,-\}$, we can derive $\Gamma \vdash T_1 \subseteq T_2 : \Omega/\{+,-\}$.
  - The remaining rules are as one would expect.

And here I ran out of imagination. Now I have the following questions:

- Is what I've sketched so far sound? What sanity checks can I use to make sure I'm not doing something wrong? Perhaps something akin to automated testing in computer programming?
- A type system with polymorphism and subtyping must have bounded quantification. How hard should it be to add?
- A very important desideratum in type systems with subtyping is that the inhabitants of each kind form a lattice. How hard should it be make sure that each kind is a lattice?
- What's the most convenient tool for mechanizing formal systems like the one I sketched? Preferably, I'd like a library or framework that already does the “boring stuff”, like implementing variable substitution and handling contexts.

Comment: What do $\Omega$ and $V$ range over?

Comment: @MartinBerger: $V$ ranges over variances. $\Omega$ doesn't range over anything: $\Omega/V$ means “a proper type (as opposed to a type operator) that can be used with $V$-variantly”.

Comment: @MartinBerger: As for individual variances, $\emptyset$ means “invariant” (the type can appear in both covariant and contravariant position), $\{+\}$ means “covariant” (the type can't appear in contravariant position), $\{-\}$ means “contravariant” (the type can't appear in covariant position” and $\{+,-\}$ means “bivariant” (the type can't be used at all).

Comment: Do you intend that subtyping and subkinding are related?

Comment: @MartinBerger: Yes. For instance, if I Church-encode `Nat` and `Pos` (TaPL p. 398-399), then `Pos` is a subtype of `Nat` at $\Omega/\{+\}$ (as expected), but `Nat` is a subtype of `Pos` at $\Omega/\{-\}$ (contravariance flips the subtype relation), and *both* are subtypes of each other at $\Omega/\{+,-\}$. More generally, if $K_1 \subsetneq K_2$, there will be types $T_1, T_2 : K_1$ such that $T_1 \not\subseteq T_2 : K_1$ but $T_1 \subseteq T_2 : K_2$.

Comment: @MartinBerger: I have a hunch that explicitly tracking variances could fix the problems that arise when combining polymorphism and subtyping, like the non-existence of joins and meets. If this alone doesn't fix it, then I might also need to extend kinding contexts, so that type variables are bounded both by above and below.